# How to update Azure App Function Configuration by REST Api

Tags: azure-functions

I have an Azure Function App.

I would like to update the Application settings for the app.

[image]

Like changing the value for the key AA, in the example shown.

Where can I find a REST API that does that?

I have found one for azure app configuration but these configurations are not used by the function app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/rest-api

Any help is very appreciated.

BR Kresten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function apps are just app services so the following REST API should work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/update-application-settings